# Stop video (something like a screenshot) in Hitfilm 3 Express

Tags: editing, screenshot

I am new in any kind of video cutting programs. I started using Hitfilm 3 Express, becuase it's free and simple to use, I think. I'm wondering if and how it is possible to make a video stop for as example 5 seconds, show up a text (to explain something) and then let the video go on. Currently im doing this by splitting the video in two parts, make a screenshot of the scene i want and then insert this screenshot between the two videoparts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to do this is with a speed effect.  Create a cut around the one frame you want to render as a still.  Your timeline should look like this:

```
motion-before | single frame | motion-after
```

You can then place a speed effect on the single frame, slow it down to 0% playback speed, and it will happily play forever if you want.  Stretch single frame to 5 seconds of length (120 frames at 24fps) and then composite your text on top.

People do this all the time.  Some applications have a "freeze frame effect" which is precisely setting the speed to zero for a default number of seconds.